# Can't remove warning about removing files from iCloud desktop

Tags: icloud, macos

The option, "show warning before removing from iCloud Drive" option is missing from the Finder preferences menu. So, each time I try to send something to the trash, the warning pops up.

Any thoughts on why it would be missing, how I can get it back?

OS: 10.11.6 (El Capitan)[image]
Mac Pro Early 2008

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you're running El Capitan. If I'm not mistaken, the feature was added in Sierra.

Comment: Actually, it **is** the answer. It's simply not there in El Capitan, but is in High Sierra. idk if it was added for 10.12 or 10.13.

Comment: isn´t here a Unix command to disable it ? I can not upgrade my OS, El capitan is the last supported thanx